# Should I create abstract methods when my abstract class implements an interface?

Tags: php, class, oop, interface, abstract-class

Given the following:

```
interface SomeInterface {

    public function foo();
    public function bar();

}

abstract class BaseClass implements SomeInterface {

    public function baz() {
        echo 'baz'; // Shared logic
    }

}

class ConcreteClass extends BaseClass {

    public function foo() {
        // foo logic...
    }

    public function bar() {
         // bar logic...
    }

{
```

This works as is, however, I'm wondering if I should add the interface methods as abstract methods in the `BaseClass` like so:

```
abstract class BaseClass implements SomeInterface {

    abstract public function foo();

    abstract public function bar();

    public function baz() {
        echo 'baz'; // Shared logic
    }

}
```

What is best practice in this case?

Comment: There is no need for the abstract declarations as any extending class will need to implement the interface's methods anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm wondering if I should add the interface methods as abstract methods in the BaseClass

No, there's no need for that and unless you want to have concrete implementation in your abstract class there's no benefit from doing that. Class extending your abstract class will have to provide implementation to fulfil satisfy interface anyway.